# Find Row Index and Column labels in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with ~1500 columns and 900 observations in the below format.
I am trying to store the row index, column label and value for each combination when cell value is > 0.75. Can someone please help with the python code to achieve this.

[image]

Thanks
Aakash

Comment: do you have any code to share for what you have tried so far? also please post your data as a copyable format so people can paste into their IDE, as opposed to a picture/screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most pythonic way, but you could iterate over every column and find the relevant rows for which entry is `>= 0.75`.

```
mappings = []
for i in df.columns:
    res = df[df[i]>=0.75].index.tolist()
    for j in res:
        mappings.append((i,j,df[i][j]))
```